# error conflicting types for 'delete_node' on the return type of type struct

Tags: c, binary-search-tree

This is **struct**

```
typedef struct node{
    int data;
    struct node *left;
    struct node *right;
}node;
node* insert(node*, int);
node* delete_n(node* ,int);
```

**delete_node** function

```
node *delete_node(node* root,int k){
    if(root==NULL){
        printf("absent");
        return root;
    }
    if(k > root->data){
        root->right=delete_node(root->right,k);
    }else if(k < root->data){
        root->left=delete_node(root->left,k);
    }else{
        if(root->left==NULL){
            node* temp=root->right;
            free(root);
            printf("deleted");
            return temp;
        }else if(root->right == NULL){
            node* temp= root->left;
            free(root);
            printf("deleted");
            return temp;
        }else if(root->left!=NULL && root->right!=NULL){
            node* temp=root->left;
            while(temp && temp->right!=NULL){
                temp=temp->right;
            }
            root->data=temp->data;
            root->left=delete_node(root->left,temp->data);
        }
    }
    return root;
}
```

I'm getting error conflicting types only when i place a return type of type **node*** but when i remove return type the code run successfully.

Comment: `delete_n` and `delete_node` are not same!

Comment: Your compiler should probably show a warning about implicit declaration which means that you don't have a correct declaration of the function. The default return type is `int`. Without seeing a [mre] it is difficult to tell.